# How to separate the variables of a particular column in a CSV file and write to a CSV file in R?

Tags: regex, r, csv

I have a CSV file like

```
Market,CampaignName,Identity
Wells Fargo,Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro,56
EMC,Los Angeles CA MetroBoston MA Metro,78
Apple,Cupertino CA Metro,68
```

Desired Output to a CSV file with the first row as the headers

```
Market,City,State,Identity
Wells Fargo,Gary,IN,56
Wells Fargo,Chicago,IL,56
EMC,Los Angeles,CA,78
EMC,Boston,MA,78
Apple,Cupertino,CA,68

res <- 
  gsub('(.*) ([A-Z]{2})*Metro (.*) ([A-Z]{2}) .*','\\1,\\2:\\3,\\4',
  xx$Market)
```

How to modify the above regular expressions to get the result in R?
New to R, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
xx.to.split <- with(xx, setNames(gsub("Metro", "", as.character(CampaignName)), Market))
do.call(rbind, str_match_all(xx.to.split, "(.+?) ([A-Z]{2}) ?"))[, -1]
```

Produces:

```
            [,1]          [,2]
Wells Fargo "Gary"        "IN"
Wells Fargo "Chicago"     "IL"
EMC         "Los Angeles" "CA"
EMC         "Boston"      "MA"
Apple       "Cupertino"   "CA"
```

This should work even if you have different number of Compaign Names in each market.  Unfortunately I think base options are annoying to implement because frustratingly there isn't a `gregexec`, although I'd be curious if someone comes up with something comparably compact in base.

Comment: How to put the header names?

Comment: the solution is not right, how to write the information onto a CSV file?

Comment: The solution is not right???  This is at this point beginning to knock on the door of I'm not going to [read any intro manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) and then hold you accountable for your free advice as if though I've paid.  I'm a bit annoyed and  did even answer the question.

Comment: @TylerRinker : From the above solution I am getting the right result but when writing to the CSV file the first column never shows up?Why? and how to solve it.

Comment: It's ok to be a beginner, it's the arrogance in the response that "the solution is not right".  A better approach would be, "Thank you so much for the free advice.  I appreciate your time.  This get's me very close to where I want but the csv column never shows up"  The answer is you have a matrix with named rows, you want a data.frame that moves those rows (`rownames`) to a column. @G. Grothendieck's answer does this.  Also people generally avoid multistep problems like this.  They ask specific problems, otherwise it smacks of do my work for me.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks for the help, G. Grothendieck's answer solves it, but also I wish to know that if there is an extra column like 'Identity' how to include that as well? The number of columns are not limited to just 2 columns. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: @TylerRinker Posted a new Question, Any help is appreciated, it will help me a lot to do more exercises. Q>"How to include a new column when using base R?"

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using base R.  Split the `CampaignName` column on the string `Metro` adding sequential numbers as names.  `stack` turns it into a data frame with columns `ind` and `values` which we massage into `DF1`.  Merge that with `xx` by the sequence numbers of `DF1` and the row numbers of `xx`.  Move `Market` to the front of `DF2` and remove `ind` and `CampaignName`.  Finally write it out.

```
xx <- read.csv("Campaign.csv", as.is = TRUE)

s <- strsplit(xx$CampaignName, " Metro")
names(s) <- seq_along(s)
ss <- stack(s) 
DF1 <- with(ss, data.frame(ind, 
    City = sub(" ..$", "", values),
    State = sub(".* ", "", values)))

DF2 <- merge(DF1, xx, by.x = "ind", by.y = 0)

DF <- DF2[ c("Market", setdiff(names(DF2), c("ind", "Market", "CampaignName"))) ]

write.csv(DF, file = "myfile.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

*REVISED* to handle extra columns after poster modified the question to include such.  Minor improvements.

Comment: If there are other columns as well like Identity,CampaignName,Market,URL how to include them as well? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Merge will not work here because there are lots of 'Wells Fargo'

Comment: I have modified the question, please refer to it.