# How to separate the string in a column of a CSV file and write to another CSV file in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file

```
Market,CampaignName
Wells Fargo,Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro
EMC,Los Angeles CA MetroBoston MA Metro
Apple,Cupertino CA Metro
```

The partial code used is

```
library(stringr)
xx.to.split <- with(xx, setNames(gsub("Metro", "", as.character(CampaignName)), Market))
do.call(rbind, str_match_all(xx.to.split, "(.+?) ([A-Z]{2}) ?"))[, -1]
```

The output is

```
                                [,1]          [,2]
                    Wells Fargo "Gary"        "IN"
                    Wells Fargo "Chicago"     "IL"
                    EMC         "Los Angeles" "CA"
                    EMC         "Boston"      "MA"
                    Apple       "Cupertino"   "CA"
```

And the desired output to the CSV file with the first row as the headers

```
Market,City,State
Wells Fargo,Gary,IN
Wells Fargo,Chicago,IL
EMC,Los Angeles,CA
EMC,Boston,MA
Apple,Cupertino,CA
```

How to write the output to a CSV file in R? New to R.

Comment: write.csv(data, "data.csv")

Comment: This question is a result of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030262/how-to-separate-the-variables-of-a-particular-column-in-a-csv-file-and-write-to). Look into `write.csv` via `help(write.csv)`.

Comment: @BlueMagister :How to include the headers as specified in the desired output? I have clearly specified the desired result and the result that I am getting.

Comment: @BlueMagister The format is not right and so not getting the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly you're getting at. Maybe the best case is to write the header yourself and then write in the matrix you have. If your object is a matrix `m`:

```
ff <- file("filename.csv", open = "wt")
writeLines("Market,City,State", con = ff)
write.table(m, file = ff, sep = ",", row.names = TRUE, 
  col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
close(ff)
```

The resulting file looks like:

```
Market,City,State
Wells Fargo,Gary,IN
Wells Fargo,Chicago,IL
EMC,Los Angeles,CA
EMC,Boston,MA
Apple,Cupertino,CA
```

Comment: The first column of the 'Market' never really shows up in the CSV file? How to write to the CSv file the 'Market' Column as well?

Comment: That should be handled with `row.names = TRUE`. I've edited my answer to show what the resulting file looks like for me. If this isn't working for you, please tell me what you get by editing your question.