# How to modify regex expression in R?

Tags: regex, r, csv

I have a CSV file as

```
AdvertiserName,Market
Wells Fargo,Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro
EMC,Los Angeles CAMetro Boston MA Metro
Apple,Cupertino CA Metro
```

and the expression in regex is

```
res <- 
 gsub('(.*) ([A-Z]{2})*Metro (.*) ([A-Z]{2}) .*','\\1,\\2:\\3,\\4',
  xx$Market)
```

And now the 'Market' column is like 'Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro' instead of 'Gary INMetro Chicago IL Metro' and the CSV file is like

```
AdvertiserName,CampaignName
Wells Fargo,Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro
EMC,Los Angeles CA MetroBoston MA Metro
Apple,Cupertino CA Metro
```

How to modify the expression in regex so as to get the desired output as

```
AdvertiserName,City,State
Wells Fargo,Gary,IN
Wells Fargo,Chicago,IL
EMC,Los Angeles,CA
EMC,Boston,MA
Apple,Cupertino,CA
```

New to R. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "And now the 'Market' column is like 'Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro' instead of 'Gary IN MetroChicago IL Metro'". Huh? What's the difference?

Comment: @Hugh :Changed it , thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `strsplit`:

```
# read file
dat <- read.csv("filename.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# split strings
splitted <- strsplit(dat$CampaignName, 
                     "( (?=[A-Z]{2}))|((?<=[A-Z]{2}) [A-Z][a-z]+)", perl = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Gary"    "IN"      "Chicago" "IL"     
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "Los Angeles" "CA"          "Boston"      "MA"         
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "Cupertino" "CA"       

# create one data frame
setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
                               mapply(cbind, 
                                      dat$AdvertiserName, 
                                      lapply(splitted, function(x)
                                        matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))))), 
         c("AdvertiserName", "City", "State"))
#   AdvertiserName        City State
# 1    Wells Fargo        Gary    IN
# 2    Wells Fargo     Chicago    IL
# 3            EMC Los Angeles    CA
# 4            EMC      Boston    MA
# 5          Apple   Cupertino    CA
```

Comment: Where to learn regex for  R? any idea, and also thanks for the suggestion and the answer.

Comment: @user3188390 Did you have a look at `?regex`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit dirty. Edits welcome.

```
 # Read in the csv file (saved here as a .txt) to 
    y <- readLines("Stackoverflow20140226.txt")


# Every time see a state, shove a comma in
for (i in seq(y)){
y[[i]] <- gsub("([A-Z]{2}) ", "\\1, ", y[[i]])
}

tf <- tempfile()
writeLines(y, tf)

# Trick the csv file into thinking there are more columns
ncol <- max(count.fields(tf, sep = ","))
x <- read.csv(tf, fill = TRUE, header = FALSE, skip=1,
         col.names = paste("V", seq_len(ncol), sep = ""))
unlink(tf)
# Use reshape to melt the data frame
library(reshape2)
xx <- melt(x, id.vars=1, measure.vars = 2:ncol(x))

xx$variable <- NULL
names(xx) <- c("AdvertiserName", "CampaignName")

xx
  AdvertiserName     CampaignName
1    Wells Fargo          Gary IN
2            EMC   Los Angeles CA
3          Apple     Cupertino CA
4    Wells Fargo  MetroChicago IL
5            EMC   MetroBoston MA
6          Apple            Metro
7    Wells Fargo            Metro
8            EMC            Metro
9          Apple
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032481/how-to-include-a-new-column-when-using-base-r , please refer to the URL that will give you a better Idea, thanks for the help,I appreciate your time and effort, maybe the solution is slightly different from my requirement because using for loop in R as far my experience is not a good idea, moreover I have million of rows of data. Any further help is appreciated.